# Word present and everywhere

Tags: grammar

Which is the correct one?
1. God is present everywhere
2. God is present at everywhere
3. God presents everywhere
4. God presents at everywhere

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is correct.
"Present" is used in ***adjective*** here and it means "being or existing in a specified place" so "present" can not be used as verbs like the third and fourth sentences.
There is no need to use the preposition "at" in the second sentences, just write everywhere is enough.

Comment: I agree.  But in formal medical writing the expression *The patient presented with ...* is often encountered, meaning that the patient turned up with some symptom or symptoms.  So I suppose God's doctor might write *God presents everywhere* as the start of a sentence ?